# How to get window screen width using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, screen-size, intro.js

```
Private Sub axsGuide_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles axsGuide.ServerClick
    Dim err_no As Long

    If Session("is_app") IsNot Nothing Then
        err_no = db.ExecuteUpdate("UPDATE users SET intro_mobile='' WHERE id='" & db.sqlDouble(Session("user_id").ToString) & "'")
        Session.Add("intro_mobile", "")
    Else
        err_no = db.ExecuteUpdate("UPDATE users SET intro_web='' WHERE id='" & db.sqlDouble(Session("user_id").ToString) & "'")
        Session.Add("intro_web", "")
    End If

    If Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("default") = False Then
        Response.Redirect("default")
    End If
End Sub
```

This is my code, actualy this one is a click button to replay intro.js, i got two intro.js which are for web view and mobile, before this i just make its automatically start based on screen width in js but now i using vb which is for one same button for web and mobile but show the different intro js based on screen width.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window) Please look at the later answers too, not just the accepted answer, because things have advanced since 2010.